# Raspberry Pi bridge eth0\eth1

Tags: networking, ethernet, bridge, netplan

I have a Raspberry Pi and a device/sensor which connects to the Pi via eth1. Eth0 is connected to my router, giving access to the internet.

I'd like to bridge my eth0/eth1, so that traffic from the device can go to the internet.

I'd like to do this using a [netplan](https://netplan.io/). Here is what I have so far:

```
network:
    version: 2
    renderer: networkd
ethernets:
    eth0:
        dhcp4: no
    eth1:
        dhcp4: no
bridges:
    br0:
        interfaces: [eth0, eth1]
```

How can I tell my system to use this netplan? Is it configured correctly? Do I need to use `dhcp4: yes` anywhere and for the `br0`, do I need to include any additional parameters?

I really have no idea what I am doing here, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: *"Do I need to use dhcp4: yes anywhere"* -> Not familiar with netplans but presuming that means a dhcp **client** then probably yes with eth0, since your router will be running a dhcp **server** and you need to interact with that if you want an IP address and a working uplink.

Comment: @goldilocks if dhcp is used, it should be with the bridge self interface br0, not eth0 or eth1 which are now bridge ports.